# How to combine two rows value into one and perform the same action in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable

Based on the common value of Country and City. I want to group rows and provide single button for any action which will be applicable for both the records. eg below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This sort of behavior isn't supported in `lightning-datatable`. You'll want to write your own custom component if you need this sort of behavior.

Comment: Thanks. can this be achieved through custom table?

Comment: @LokeshKumar Yes, you can certainly make your own table.